# How can I use Keyboard Shortcuts in WxPython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Well, I have a simple text editor, the code will be published below.
So, I wish I could call File/Open for CTRL+o, File/Save for CTRL+s, File/Save as for CTRL+Shift+s.
But in addition, I need that when I press CTRL+1, CTRL+2, CTRL+3, CTRL+4, I have the ability to use code other than WxPython.
As I know, WxPython has a KeyEvent class with these key events, but to use it, as I understood, I need to use bind.
Well, I've tried Keyboard Shortcuts (Accelerators), but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me please?

```
import os
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(800,600))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open"," Open a file")
        menuSave = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "&Save"," Save a file")
        menuSaveAs = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "&Save as"," Save a file as")
        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, menuSave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSaveAs, menuSaveAs)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
        exit_id = wx.NewId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnKeyExit, id=exit_id)
        a_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('Q'), exit_id )])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(a_tbl)
        self.Show(True)
...
    def onKeyExit(self, e):
            self.Close()
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Test")
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN`

Bind this either to `self` or `self.control`.

You will need to check both the key and check if a modifier key is also depressed.

```
import os
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(800,600))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open"," Open a file")
        menuSave = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "&Save"," Save a file")
        menuSaveAs = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "&Save as"," Save a file as")
        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, menuSave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSaveAs, menuSaveAs)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)

        self.control.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnKey(self, event):
        key = event.KeyCode
        print("Testing key ", chr(key))
        if key < 49 or key > 52:
            event.Skip()
            return
        # Test modifier key there is no wx.WXK_CONTROL_0....9
        if event.ControlDown():
            self.OnOther(key)
        event.Skip()

    def OnOther(self, key):
        print("Control >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", chr(key))

    def OnOpen(self, e):
        self.dirname = ''
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.FD_OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r', encoding="utf8")
            self.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()
    def OnSave(self, e):
        try:
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w', encoding='utf8')
            f.write(self.control.GetValue())
            f.close()
        except:
            try:
                dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save to file:", ".", "", "*.*", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
                if (dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
                    self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
                    self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
                    f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w', encoding='utf8')
                    f.write(self.control.GetValue())
                    f.close()
                dlg.Destroy()
            except:
                pass
    def OnSaveAs(self, event):
        try:
            dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save to file:", ".", "", "*.*", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
            if (dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
                self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
                self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
                f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w', encoding='utf8')
                f.write(self.control.GetValue())
                f.close()
            dlg.Destroy()
        except:
            pass
    def OnAbout(self, e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A Record text editor", "About Sample Editor", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
    def OnExit(self, e):
        self.Close(True)
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Test")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This looks not understandible, especially since WxPython has Keyboard Shortcuts Accelerators, my code doesn't throw errors, but it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: When you run `the above` code, what if anything prints out?

Comment: Nothing! As I said, this works without errors, but my OnKeyExit method is obviously not executing

Comment: @ConstantineRyzhikov Try replacing `wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN` with `wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK`. You don't mention your operating system, that may help in working out what the issue is.

Comment: But I don't use key down, I use Keyboard Shortcuts (Accelerators).

Comment: A question should be clear and concise. If you make statements like `when I press CTRL+1, CTRL+2, CTRL+3, CTRL+4` people reading that, will take it literally. If in addition, you talk of `KeyEvent class with these key events`, I fail too see, unless we are mind readers, what other interpretation would be expected. Better perhaps, that you edit your question to ask specifically for what you to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If on the other hand, you wish to restrict yourself to using menu accelerators, you include the keys required after a tab character in the menu label.
Additionally there is the option to use an accelerator table (https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.AcceleratorTable.html)

```
import os
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(800,600))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        othermenu = wx.Menu()
        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open"," Open a file")
        menuSave = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "&Save"," Save a file")
        menuSaveAs = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "&Save as"," Save a file as")
        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")

        menuOth1 = othermenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Option &1\tCtrl+1"," Run option 1")
        menuOth2 = othermenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Option &2\tCtrl+2"," Run option 2")
        menuOth3 = othermenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Option &3\tCtrl+3"," Run option 3")
        menuOth4 = othermenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Option &4\tCtrl+4"," Run option 4")
                        
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File")
        menuBar.Append(othermenu,"&Other")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, menuSave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSaveAs, menuSaveAs)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOtherKey, id=menuOth1.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOtherKey, id=menuOth2.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOtherKey, id=menuOth3.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOtherKey, id=menuOth4.GetId())                

        self.Show(True)

    def OnOtherKey(self, event):
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        label = obj.GetLabel(event.Id)
        print(label)

    def OnOpen(self, e):
        self.dirname = ''
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.FD_OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r', encoding="utf8")
            self.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnSave(self, e):
        try:
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w', encoding='utf8')
            f.write(self.control.GetValue())
            f.close()
        except:
            try:
                dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save to file:", ".", "", "*.*", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
                if (dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
                    self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
                    self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
                    f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w', encoding='utf8')
                    f.write(self.control.GetValue())
                    f.close()
                dlg.Destroy()
            except:
                pass

    def OnSaveAs(self, event):
        try:
            dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save to file:", ".", "", "*.*", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
            if (dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
                self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
                self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
                f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w', encoding='utf8')
                f.write(self.control.GetValue())
                f.close()
            dlg.Destroy()
        except:
            pass

    def OnAbout(self, e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A Record text editor", "About Sample Editor", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self, e):
        self.Close(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Test")
app.MainLoop()
```